# Unable to use progress dialog with parse API in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parse-platform, progressdialog

I am trying to show a progressbar dialogue while my

**ParseUser.logInInBackground**

checks the validity of user but I am unable to do so.
Also I read that there is bug in parse that hinders doing so, can someone please tell me if that is possible and help me with the code, or should i just make a fake progress bar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced a similar situation. What I ended up doing was the following.

```
private Dialog progressDialog;
```

define two methods to keep track of the progress bar showing or dismissing. Something like this.

```
public void showProgressBar(String msg){
   progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", message, true);
}

public void dismissProgressBar(){
   if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
         progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

call `showProgressBar(message)` before login method.

`showProgressBar(message);` then,
`ParseUser.logInBackground`. Then, Inside `done` method, call `dismissProgressBar();`